# wallet.dat from 2014 shown as empty with latest client 0.18

Tags: wallet.dat

I have bitcoin wallet from 2014. I have saved it encrypted. 
Since then I haven't checked it, until now. 
I did sync the whole bitcoin block-chain and when copy my wallet.dat and re-scan wit the client, the wallet got shown as empty. My wallet.dat is 88kb.
Bitcon core Client dump of the wallet shows addresses only from 2019 and wallet keys dump from the client returns error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which platform are you on?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional.
My wallet originally was saved as file not encrypted. So the client do not need password to read it.

Comment: how did you ensure you found the correct data directory?

Comment: wallallet.dat resides in the client's exe folder.
In 2014 I did try to copy out wallet.dat and then remove it back. So the client did show 0 and xx bitcoins respectively.
Now when i sync the whole block chain and  copy my wallet.dat from 2014 into client's exe folder my balance is 0, seems like no wallet at all.
So I wonder why ?

Comment: You can't swap out wallets without doing a rescan, AFAIK. Bitcoin Core minimizes space usage and doesn't store histories for addresses it doesn't control. So even though all the blockchain is synced, you'd need to restart with a rescan parameter to scan the blockchain with the wallet that you have placed there.

Comment: I did sync the whole block-chain and then did copy my wallet.dat into client's exe folder and  did restart the client with -rescan option. So after the re scan the client still shows zero in my wallet wallet balance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you resolve this issue for yourself? If not, please do the following. First remove save your wallet.dat file into another folder on your pc. Second remove BTC Core entirely from your pc and restart the pc. Finally, reinstall BTC Core onto the pc. Go into the wallet directory, rename new wallet.dat which is created. Place backup wallet.dat file here. Restart BTC Core client and let it rescan the network. This will fix your issue.

Comment: I will try this, will give feedback. Thank you.